# Can I use an AutFac factory to create my DbContext

Tags: c#, asp.net, dependency-injection, autofac

I am trying to implement an auto-refresh using MemoryCache by specifying a CacheEntryUpdateCallback delegate that is called when the cached item expires.
The delegate calls a method in my repository:

```
public async Task<List<Foo>> GetFoos()
{
   return await _dbContext.Foos.ToListAsync();
}
```

That throws an exception in the callback because the context has already been disposed (the original HttpRequest has long since returned)

So I tried using an Autofac factory to inject my dependency instead:

```
public FooRepository(Func<<IFooContext> dbContextFactory)
{
    _dbContextFactory = dbContextFactory;
}

public async Task<List<Foo>> GetFoos()
{
   return await _dbContextFactory().Foos.ToListAsync();
}
```

That gave me a different exception:

> Instances cannot be resolved and nested lifetimes cannot be created
>   from this LifetimeScope as it has already been disposed.

What about this "Owned" factory thing?

```
public FooRepository(Func<Owned<IFooContext>> dbContextFactory)
{
    _dbContextFactory = dbContextFactory;
}

public async Task<List<Foo>> GetFoos()
{
   using(var factory = _dbContextFactory())
   {
       return await factory.Value.Foos.ToListAsync();
   }
}
```

Nope, same problem:

> Instances cannot be resolved and nested lifetimes cannot be created
>   from this LifetimeScope as it has already been disposed.

What can I do to get around this problem?

Answer (score 0):

you should have hosted service for long run process and kind of refresh queue to feed it

with hosted service you can get DbContext in temporary scope as follow

```
public class TimedHostedService : IHostedService
{
    private readonly IServiceScopeFactory scopeFactory;

    public TimedHostedService(IServiceScopeFactory scopeFactory)
    {
        this.scopeFactory = scopeFactory;
    }

    private void DoWork()
    {
        using (var scope = scopeFactory.CreateScope())
        {
            var dbContext = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<MyDbContext>();
        }
    }
}
```

about [hosted service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio)